# How do you show a Subject with two different Predicates that point to the same Object in a linked graph?

Tags: graph, nodes, rdf, edges

I have two triples:

```
:person :directed :movie;
        :actedIn  :movie.
```

How would I draw a linked graph to represent this?

Regarding the Object, would I have one node with two Predicates on its label between it and the Subject; or is it best to have two Object nodes that each have their own differing Predicate labels?

Comment: I don't get the question. I personally would just have to nodes with two edges connecting them. Why would you add another node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:movie` is one entity, one node.

You should have two entity nodes (`:person` and `:movie`) connected by two edges (a/k/a predicates or attributes), `:directed` and `:actedIn`.